Signed Measures and Radon-Nikodym Theorem with Total Variation Measure
This is a question from Richard Bass, Real Analysis for Graduate Students.

If $\mu$ is a signed measure on $(X,A)$ and $|\mu|$ is the total variation measure, prove that there exists a real-valued function $f$ that is measurable with respect to $A$ such that $|f| = 1 \text{ a.e.}$ with respect to $\mu$ and $d\mu = f d|\mu|$.

This is what I have so far:
"Since $\mu$ is a signed measure, by the Hahn Decomposition Theorem, we know that $X=P \cup N$, where $P$ is a positive set and $N$ is a negative set, such that they are disjoint. Now define $f=1$ on $P$, and $f=-1$ on $N$. Then, it is clear that $|f|=1 \text{ a.e.}$"
However, I am having trouble proving that $d\mu = f d|\mu|$. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Welcome to MSE! By "last part" do you mean only the part "$|f|=1 \text{ a.e.}$" ?

Sorry, I meant proving that =||.

Please edit your problem statement accordingly.

For any $E \in A$, we have
$$ \int_E d\mu = \mu(E) = \mu(E \cap P) + \mu(E \cap N) = 1.|\mu|(E \cap P) + (-1).|\mu|(E \cap N) = \int_E f d|\mu| $$
So, for all $E \in A$, $\int_E d\mu = \int_E f d|\mu|$, that means $d\mu = f d|\mu|$.

Thank you so much @Ramiro
